# Access private file in AWS S3 only from iOS / Android by Cognito

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, permissions, amazon-iam

I'd like to make my assets only accessible from either iOS / Android. not directly from website (because of copyrights issue). I've created federated cognito and applied it into the app. the app have succesfully uploaded an image (which stated that it can actually access the bucket). but still no

I've tried to use bucket policy like this :

```
{
  "Id": "Policy1493280373103",
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1493280365573",
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::ars-app-test/*",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          " arn:aws:iam::218591702438:role/Cognito_ArsUnauth_Role"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

But, it still cannot be opened (403 forbidden error) from iOS.

The best solution is creating Pre-signed URL but i thought it will took more for loading. Is there another solution for this?

Thank a lot.

Comment: Have you solved this?